# Web Reference Service doesn't work when consumed from a Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, proxy

There is a third party's `asmx` web service I need to consume in my web application. I made a console application, then I added the service as a Web Reference and everything worked just fine.

Then I moved the very same code from the console application into my web application which runs on the same computer and I cannot consume the web service anymore; I get this error message:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 11.22.33.44:1234

I don't understand why! The code of the console application is almost the same as the code of the web application and they both run on my local computer! They both have the same target version of .NET (4.5.1).

Any idea?

Comment: Nine out of ten times this is because your company utilizes a proxy server to which your Windows Service isn't authenticated. Change the credentials under which the service runs, or configure proxy authentication.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok, but what is the fundamental difference between Console App and Web App? Why does the first one work and the second one does not?

Comment: There was a question hidden in that comment. _Does_ your company use a mandatory proxy server for making outside HTTP connections? It also contained an explanation for your question: the difference is the user account that runs the code. Your Windows account authorizes against the proxy server; the service account that IIS runs under doesn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster I moved my web application from Local IIS to IISExpress (which runs under the same account as Visual Studio I start the console application from), but it didn't help.

Comment: @CodeCaster Solved! You were right, the issue was caused by wrong proxy configuration. I added the proxy explicitly in the web.config and everything works! Thank you a lot! Post it as an answer in case you need some more reputation :-)